# How to block .. in the URL with Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

I am looking for a way that you can redirect if there was (`..`) two dots in the URL.

I used

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^..^"
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

But it seems it's not working.

UPDATE answer :

```
<LocationMatch "/(.*\.\.)">
   Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from  all
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule "(.*)\.\.(.*)" "$1$2"`

The above command will remove '..' from a request.  $1 and $2 are the first grouped bracket and second respectively.  '.' is any character, '*' means repeat it zero or more times.  '\' escapes the next character, so '\.' means a literal full stop.